# How to automate graph building and saving using Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api

Say I have three variables (x,y, and z). I want to plot y against x for each value of the categorical variable z, and then save it in a specific folder. Using R and tidyverse, a simplified code would be something like,

```
for (i in z){
filter(data,z==i)%>%
ggplot(aes(x,y))+geom_line()
ggsave(paste("myfolder/test_",i,".png")
}
```

Comment: If you Tableau Server (besides desktop), you could probably do this with tabcmd. But that doesn't work for Tableau Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have Tableau Server, as I am just playing around with their student account. Do you think this can be done in Tableau Public? which seems to have some of the Tableau Server functionalities?

Comment: No, it needs administrator privileges as fas as I know. Tabcmd won't be possible on Tableau Public.